# append child node to xml output of Log4Net

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, log4net

i tried to use Log4Net for the first time.

i created a layout class to be used on log4net output:

```
public class MyXmlLayout : XmlLayoutBase
{
    protected override void FormatXml(XmlWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
            writer.WriteStartElement("LogEntry");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("id", loggingEvent.ThreadName);
            writer.WriteStartElement(loggingEvent.MessageObject.ToString());
            writer.WriteString(loggingEvent.LoggerName);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

i want to have an output as the following:

```
<LogEntry id=1>
    <Begin>MethodName</Begin>
    <ExecutionTimeInSec>3473784</ExecutionTimeInSec>
    <End>MethodName</End>
</Logentry>
```

But all i got is the following:

```
    <LogEntry id=1><Begin>MethodName</Begin></LogEntry>
    <LogEntry id=1><ExecutionTimeInSec>3473784</ExecutionTimeInSec></LogEntry>
    <LogEntry id=1><End>MethodName</End></LogEntry>
```

i tried loading the XmlDocument but it says it is being used by another process which i understand is being used by log4net currently

is there a way to check if the LogEntry node with specific id exists before adding another node?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, the output does not fit your code and what you want as output does also not correspondent with your code. There are a few improvements to get you started:

loggingEvent.MessageObject.ToString() should not be used to get the message, use: loggingEvent.RenderedMessage

As far as I can see you have to check if your code is even configured to run in your configuration. Please have a look at this blog post to get you started with the configuration and how to use the XmlLayoutBase:

[log4net-rollingfileappender-with-xml](http://www.mikebevers.be/blog/2010/09/log4net-rollingfileappender-with-xml/)